# What type should I use in an Rx stream for notifications purpose?

Tags: events, flutter, reactive-programming, rxdart

I build a flutter app using `RxDart` and I want to create a stream of click events. What type should this stream contain? `bool` would probably work for me, but I'll always stream `true`s. Is there any best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Stream<void>`:

```
final clickEventStream = PublishSubject<void>();
```

When you are listening to the stream, ignore the argument using an underscore:

```
clickEventStream.listen((_) { ... })
```

To push new events to the stream, just add `null` (it's a valid value for `void`):

```
clickEventStream.add(null);
```

Also see https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0